# Logging unhandled exceptions to a log file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, logging, exception

How can I log unhandled exceptions to a log file for a WinForms application so it is easy to determine the source of an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to catch unhandled exceptions. Add the VB.Net version of this code to your main program:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
```

Then add the event handlers:

```
static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (ex != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception: {0}", e.Exception);      
    }
}

static void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unhandled application exception: {0}", e.Exception);
}
```

Then you can log the errors with your chosen log method.. (Sorry for the C# code!)

Comment: if i am using the try catch @ form level then what i have to write in catch block to get executed above code?

Comment: If you use try/catch, just add the logging code to the catch block - this is to pick up **unhandled** exceptions, i.e. those that did not get caught in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Sub Main`, or the constructor for your start up form, add the following code:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledExceptionHandler
```

Then, add the following method to your `Sub Main`, or add it as a shared method in any other class/form:

```
Public Sub UnhandledExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    If TypeOf e.ExceptionObject Is Exception Then
        Dim ex As Exception = CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
        ' Log the exception
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to log, use Nlog - it writes log messages to file, email and so on.
Link:
http://nlog-project.org/

The documentation:
https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial

Then you can simply do this:

```
Private Logger As NLog.Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
try
'do stuff
catch
logger.fatal("Messagedescription")
end try
```

this would automatically write your message to the file specified in the nlog.config file
To view the log you could use any editor or logExpert, which I like.